# Terrible screen resolution after installing win 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, resolution

I set my (tv-monitor) Samsung LN32A550P3FXZC to its native 1920x1080 60Hz-32bit res. My actual res became 1536x864? NVIDIA GeForce 8800GT has latest driver and working properly. Using HDMI/DVI cables.
Tried playing with Visual C, with no luck.
The bottom line is that it's the same pc and monitor as before with XP, so is it a setting in win7 ?
Appreciate any advice to a novice

Comment: Is Windows 7 32-bit or 64-bit? What do you mean exactly by "playing with Visual C"? Are you able to [change the screen resolution](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-your-screen-resolution) manually? What are the available resolutions? Which driver version is currently installed?

Comment: Did you recently attempt a clean install of Windows 7? ...reimage a hard drive? ...run the manufacturer's system recovery?

Answer (score 0):

It's a 32 bit. At one point it asked for Visual ++ Redistributable for better display so I allowed its installation to no better effect.I can change it from the recommended 1080 all the way to 800x600. Latest driver 335.23  version 9.18.13.3523 (Mar 10/14) Bios v 62.92.1f.0.65
Thanks for trying to help